# Why is my CSS not being applied with HTML in Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

Store link: mekarwangi.myshopify.com
Password: vaipre

I'm using the Impulse theme on Shopify. My aim is to put some space between the div and other elements on the page. I have 2 main issues. The first is:

I added a div in my product-template.liquid file, the html is:

```
<div id = "replies"> Typically replies within 2-3 days! </div>
```

The css in the theme.css.liquid file is:

```
#replies{
       margin-top: 15px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

For some reason, the css isn't being applied to the div today, even though it was yesterday. This is super weird as it should be extremely simple and straightforward.

My second issue is the same, css isn't being applied to html in the same file.

html:

```
<div class="product-single__description rte" id = "productdescription">
                {{ product.description }}
              </div>
```

css:

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      #productdescription{
      text-align: center;
      }
    }
```

Both these methods worked yesterday but for some reason don't work today. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked inside the navigator (F12) which attributes are applied?

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding and started with Shopify..so far all the changes to css have been made in the theme.css.liquid file and html changes in their respective sections. I'm not too sure what you're referring to when you say navigator. Would you mind clarifying? Thank you!

Comment: I mean checking with Chrome or your favorite. Press F12, select the "Select element" icon in left side, and then check the styles/computed in the right side

Comment: It gives me links to various css files, so I'm not 100% sure which one you're talking about, but it doesn't show the css properties I linked to it

Comment: Taka a look https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Comment: you need to share the URL, so someone checks and tell what is the actual reason it doesn't work.

Comment: added my store link, it's Store link: mekarwangi.myshopify.com Password: vaipre

Comment: the issue is here you tag `#your-request` is not closed properly, https://prnt.sc/x0xx4k

Comment: How do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: post an answer, you accept it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here you tag #your-request is not closed properly. [image]

Comment: Thank you for answering! May I ask how did you get access to my css file? How do I do it from Chrome? Thank you!

Comment: once you navigate to the page you can see the source code of the page using `view page source`, right-click using a mouse, and the context menu has the option.[https://prnt.sc/x53dmm]

Comment: where you can list the HTML code and links of JS and CSS files.[https://prnt.sc/x53g02]

Comment: once you click over the link it opens the CSS code. [https://prnt.sc/x53i3s]

Comment: any idea why it comes messily (as one big paragraph) instead of proper lines for the css when I try it for goceb.com?

Comment: Shopify has default `file.scss.liquid` which is an `SCSS` file and Shopify serves the file in a compressed format to reduce the load time.